# Tkinter how to continuously update a label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a clock in tkinter, and I am attempting to update a label whenever the time changes: However, I have no idea how to do this. I have tried the after method. However, I believe I am doing something wrong.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
date = date.today()
now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

root = Tk()
root.title("Clock")
root.geometry("500x500")
Time = Label(root, text = f"{time}", font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
Time.place(x = "160", y = "100")
def Update():
    Time.config(text = f"{time}")
    
root.after(1000, Update())

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `root.after` takes a function, not the result of a function:

```py
root.after(1000, Update)
```

Secondly, you need some way to make the update happen every second, rather than just once.  The easiest way is to add a `root.after` call to your `Update` function, as well as calculating the new time string each time the function is called:

```py
def Update():
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    Time.config(text = f"{time}")
    root.after(1000, Update)
```

Comment: PLUS you need to recompute the new `time` string, otherwise you'll display the initial time over and over.