# How to continuously print a while loop output on to TKINTER Lable

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
from cgitb import text
from decimal import Decimal
from turtle import bgcolor, width
from web3 import Web3
import time
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title('Drip Bot')
root.geometry('1600x800')
frameMain=LabelFrame(root,text="main frame")
frameContent=LabelFrame(frameMain, text="frame content")
frameCtrl=LabelFrame(frameMain,text="Control", borderwidth=2)
fromLabel=Label(frameCtrl,text="from")
fromEntry=Entry(frameCtrl,text="from")
toLabel=Label(frameCtrl,text="To")
toEntry=Entry(frameCtrl,text="from")

n=0
while True:
   n += 1
   print(n)
 screenLabel=Label(frameContent,text=n ,width=170,height=42,borderwidth=4,relief='solid')
frameCtrl.grid(row=1, column=1)
frameContent.grid(row=1, column=2)
frameMain.pack()
fromLabel.pack()
fromEntry.pack()
toLabel.pack()
toEntry.pack()
screenLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I am using a while loop in my function to print out the value of n. The issue is that I want to print n on to the label. I am confused on how to go about it. I don't know if my question is clear enough. I have tried passing  n in to the label text attributes but it doesn't show on the label. In fact, it shows that n is not defined. Please how do I achieve this? Or is it possible display my terminal or tkinter label.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355318/tkinter-how-to-continuously-update-a-label seems highly related.

Comment: There was no error at all. It prints on the terminal but not on the label as I had hoped

Answer (score -1):

Remove `text=n` in `screenLabel` parameter

Change this:

```
while True:
   n += 1
   print(n)
 screenLabel=Label(frameContent,text=n ,width=170,height=42,borderwidth=4,relief='solid')
```

to:

```
while True:
   n += 1
   print(n)
   screenLabel.configure(text=n)
   
screenLabel=Label(frameContent,,width=170,height=42,borderwidth=4,relief='solid')
```