Python, tkinter: Updating a Label periodically
I know, this topic has been adressed in several threads, e.g. this one: Tkinter how to continuously update a label, I looked through them, but what I found did not work for me. I try to update a Label with an image into which I write a new text periodically, i.e. without any event like click, enter. I tried binding the tkinter to the update method (s. variant 1 in code) here I generate a dummy event  and I tried the "after" method (variant 2 in code) but it also didn't work. Below is a minimal example. How do I manage to update this picture with text periodically?
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
Display
- Show handling hints, minimal example
'''

import tkinter
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import threading, time
import sys
root_path = r"some_path"
sys.path.append(root_path)
import version

class Display:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_path_img = os.path.join(root_path, "Images/")        
        self.teststep_image_name = "teststep.jpg"
        self.teststep_name = "teststep_init"
        self.button_height = 2
        self.button_width = 20
        self.window_width = 900
        self.teststep_height = 700
        self.frame_height = 500
        self.logo_height = 50
        self.logo_width = 100
        self.window_size = str(self.window_width) + "x400"
        self.grid_columns = 3 # vertical
        self.grid_rows = 3 # horizontal
        self.displ = tkinter.Tk()
        self.displ.maxsize = self.window_width
        self.teststep_text = "TestStep init"
        self.step_label_init()
        self.update_time = 1
        self.update_tuple = (self.teststep_image_name, self.teststep_text)
        self.n_calls = 0

        self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep)
        self.displ.mainloop()

    def step_label_init(self):
        '''Configure Label for Teststep display with image and text'''
        self.teststep_image = self.open_tk_image(self.teststep_image_name, 
                                                 self.window_width, 
                                                 self.teststep_height, 
                                                 self.teststep_text)
        self.TestStep_Label = tkinter.Label(
                                            self.displ, 
                                            bg = "white", 
                                            height = self.frame_height, 
                                            width = self.window_width,
                                            image = self.teststep_image)
        self.TestStep_Label.grid_configure(
                                            row = 2,
                                            column = 1,
                                            columnspan = 3,
                                            sticky = tkinter.NSEW)
        
        #variant 2
        #self.TestStep_Label.after(1000, self.update_img_teststep, "")

    def open_tk_image(self, img_name, img_width, img_height, test_text = ""):
        pil_image = Image.open(self.base_path_img + img_name, "r").resize((img_width, img_height))
        img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)
        textwidth = 20 
        textheight = 50
        x = img_width // 4 - textwidth
        y = img_height // 5 - textheight
        img_draw.text((x, y), test_text, fill="yellow", font_size=30)
        tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
        pil_image.close()
        return tk_image

    def update_img_teststep(self, input_ign):
        #dummy argument
        print(input_ign)
        img_name = self.update_tuple[0]
        teststep_text = self.update_tuple[1] + "number of calls: " + str(self.n_calls)
        self.teststep_image = self.open_tk_image(img_name, self.window_width, self.teststep_height, teststep_text)
        self.TestStep_Label.configure(image = self.teststep_image)
        self.n_calls += 1

    def displ_config(self):
        #test start
        for i in range(1,3):
            time.sleep(self.update_time)
            print(f'slept, now i is {i}')
            self.update_tuple = ("teststep"+str(i)+".jpg", "this is text #" + str(i))
            self.displ.configure(bg = "black")
        #test end



# import time
# import threading

if __name__ == "__main__":
    displ = Display()
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355318/tkinter-how-to-continuously-update-a-label

As described above, I tried binding tkinter.Tk() to the update method and generating a dummy event that would trigger the binding function. And I tried using the method "after" with self.displ and with the self.TestStep_Label. The second variant should have solved the problem immediately, the first variant would have needed some additional waiting calls. But actually, none of both helped.

There should be an error traceback from your use of self.displ.after( .... Please include all errors that you see.

what doesn't work? Do you get error message? Show it in question. Do you don't see image? You have to write it in question. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides code may work correctly on our computers.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

don't use for-loop with sleep because it stops tkitner and it can't update code. Tkinter (like many GUIs) doesn't redraw widgets in window at once but it wait for end of you function - to redraw all changes in one moment. This way it has less work, and it doesn't blink. Eventually you may need root.update() to force tkinter to redraw widgets in window.

after() runs function only once - so inside function you have to use another after() to run this function again, and again.

There are now errors, the code produces a gui with the initial data (image and text) and then freezes. There is no update and this is the problem.

if you runs long running code - like for-loop with sleep() - then tkinter can't run own code which check mouse/keyboard event, redraws buttons, etc. It may need to run this code in separate thread, or inside loop you can run self.disp.update() to force tkitner to update GUI. If you will do it often then GUI will have to time to work.

I didn't run you code (yet, because I don't have images for this) but I see few mistakes.
Probably more important mistake is:
after(time, funt) runs func only ONCE - so inside func you have to use again after(time, funt) to make loop which runs it again and again.
def update_img_teststep(self, input_ign):
    # ... code ...

    # run again the same function
    self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep)


You put link to question Tkinter how to continuously update a label and its answer also shows it.
I added comment to code to show it.
def Update():
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    Time.config(text = f"{time}")
    root.after(1000, Update)   # <--- run again the same function


After running code (with fake images) it shows me error because self.update_img_teststep(...) needs parameter but in after() you run it without parameter
self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep)

In other GUIs maybe it would need to use lambda
self.displ.after(self.update_time, lambda:self.update_img_teststep(some_value))

but in tkinter you can put arguments directly in after
self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep, some_value)


Code works for me if I use two changes:
def __init__(self):
    # ... code ...

    # <--- add missing arguments
    self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep, 'Hello World')
    self.displ.mainloop()

def update_img_teststep(self, input_ign):
    #dummy argument
    print(input_ign)
    img_name = self.update_tuple[0]
    teststep_text = self.update_tuple[1] + "number of calls: " + str(self.n_calls)
    self.teststep_image = self.open_tk_image(img_name, self.window_width, self.teststep_height, teststep_text)
    self.TestStep_Label.configure(image = self.teststep_image)
    self.n_calls += 1

    # <--- run again
    self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep, input_ign)        


Other ideas which can make problems with after()
If you want to control function - e.g to stop it - then you may use some variables with True/False
def __init__(self)

    self.running = True

def start_button():

    if self.running:
        print("Already running")
    else:
        self.running = True
        self.update_img_teststep(some_value)   # start again

def stop_button():

    self.running = False

def update_img_teststep(self, input_ign):
    # ... code ...

    if self.running:
        # run again the same function
        self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep, some_value)

And if you want to pause code then you may have to put code in if
def __init__(self)

    self.running = True
    self.paused  = False

def start_button():

    if self.running:
        print("Already running")
        if self.paused:
            print("But it is paused")
    else:
        self.running = True
        self.paused  = False
        self.update_img_teststep(some_value)   # start again

def stop_button():

    self.running = False
    self.paused  = False

def pause_button():

    self.paused = not self.paused

def update_img_teststep(self, input_ign):

    if not self.paused:
        # ... code ...

    if self.running:
        # run again the same function
        self.displ.after(self.update_time, self.update_img_teststep, some_value)


Other problem is for-loop with sleep() - it creates long running code, and it may freeze GUI because tkinter (like many GUIs) doesn't redraws widgets when you change value but it waits for end of your function and it readraw all changes at once. And it looks like first it freeze and later it set only last value.
Inside loop you can use self.disp.update() and tkinter will have a little time to redraw widgets, to check mouse/key event, etc.
    def displ_config(self):
        #test start
        for i in range(1, 3):
            time.sleep(self.update_time)
            print(f'slept, now i is {i}')
            self.update_tuple = ("teststep"+str(i)+".jpg", "this is text #" + str(i))
            self.displ.configure(bg = "black")
            self.disp.update()  # <--- force tkinter to update GUI - it will have also time to check mouse/key events
        #test end

For longer runnning code it may need to run it in separate thread but it can make another problem - GUIs doesn't like to make changes in widgets from thread. It may need to use Queue (or at least global variables) to send values from other thread to main thread and main thread should use after() to check periodically if there is new value in queue (in global variable) and update widgets.

Hello furas, thank you, for your help. I added the "after" statement into the update-function and now the update works fine. Thank you!

I added information about for-loop with sleep() and with root.update()
